# How to return integer in text form

Tags: templating

Is it possible to return an integer in it's text form?  I searched the Twig documentation and Stack Overflow and did not find a solution.

I could of course just set it up and create it based on the loop index,

```
{% if loop.index == '1' %}
{% set place = 'one' %}
```

but that breaks if the user creates entries above whatever number I set up to so it is not a real solution of any value. I am wondering if someone here might have a solution?

The return would be "one" in place of '1', "two" in place of '2', etc.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there is no `convertNumberToWords` type method in twig or php. However, you could create your own. This could be done in several ways: twig macro, custom twig filter, or plugin variable.

Here is an example of a simple twig macro that uses a lookup table:

```
{% macro numberToWords(integer) %}

    {% digits = {
        0:  'zero',
        1:  'one',
        2:  'two',
        3:  'three',
        4:  'four',
        5:  'five',
        6:  'six',
        7:  'seven',
        8:  'eight',
        9:  'nine',
        10: 'ten',
        11: 'eleven',
        12: 'twelve',
        13: 'thirteen',
        14: 'fourteen',
        15: 'fifteen',
        16: 'sixteen',
        17: 'seventeen',
        18: 'eighteen',
        19: 'nineteen',
    } %}

    {{ digits[integer] }}

{% endmacro %}

{% import _self as macros %}

{% for i in 1..19 %}
    {{ macros.numberToWords(loop.index) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Creating a custom twig filter or a plugin would of course allow you to use php, which might provide a more robust solution. Doing a quick search I see there are a few examples that people have written, like [this one](https://pageconfig.com/post/number-to-word-conversion-with-php).

If you want to do this via a plugin, you might try using lindseydiloreto's excellent [craft-businesslogic](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-businesslogic) as a starting point. Then just paste the php methods (from the example linked above) into the variables file (along with any dependency methods).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I did not want to keep searching if nothing exists so I appreciate you taking the time.  I will look into those links!

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late to the party, but I recently came across [this article](https://medium.com/@drifter/the-power-of-t-in-craft-3-b4bc3489edc4) on the power of `t()`

In it he does a bit of magic like this:

```
{{ 'We are {n,spellout} in line' | t({n: 138}) }} 
en-US => We are one hundred thirty-eight
hu-HU => Százharmincnyolc vagyunk
```